# Can I use InputBox to input a Hotkey?

Tags: hotkeys, autohotkey, inputbox

I'd like to use InputBox to enter the keys that would subsequently be used to activate a Hotkey  While I am able to input the data using the script below, I don't know to make it available as a Hotkey

```
InputBox, UserID, UserID, Enter your UserID,,150, 120
If ErrorLevel
    Exit
InputBox, password, Password, Enter your Password, HIDE, 150, 120 
If ErrorLevel
    Exit
Prompt := "Create your shortcut using any`ncombination of keys including `n^ for Ctrl`n# for Windows`n! for Alt`nin combination with another key."
InputBox, Shortcut, Shortcut, %Prompt%,,220, 220
If ErrorLevel
    Exit
else
MsgBox, %UserID%, %Password%, %Shortcut%
Exit

%Shortcut%::
MsgBox, It worked.
```

Probably ridiculously easy to do but I don't see it.  Is is possible?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I solved it. Might not be ideal, but it works for me.

```
!Esc::
SplashTextOn, 250,200,Power Options,1 = Arentheem Ouders`n`r2 = Arentheem Brian`n`rS = Sleep`n`rR = Reboot`n`rP = Power down`n`rW = Wait`n`rEsc = keep working`n`rL = Loop`n`rD = Display Off`n`rC = Compress MP3's and sleep`n`rB = Back-up and sleep`n`r`n`rPC will automatically go to sleep after 10 seconds if no key is pressed!
SetTimer, GoToSleep, Off
Input, CI_KeyVar, I L1 T10
SplashTextOff
if ErrorLevel = Timeout
{
    GoSub, NetBackup
    return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "c")
{

  ;SplashTextOn, 250,30,Shift+Esc = Finish Options,Sleep = default
  run "C:\Program Files (x86)\AutoHotkey\AutoHotkey.exe" "C:\Users\Robert\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Lemon Juice\Compress.ahk"
  SetTimer, MySplashTexOff, -60000 ; Remove splashText after 1 minute -60000 = run timer once
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "d")
{
  SetTimer MonitorOff, 1000 ; Turn the monitor off
  Return
}

if (CI_KeyVar = "l")
{
  GoSub, MyScreenLoop
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "1")
{
  Sleep, 500
  Send, {Esc}
  Sleep, 100
  Send, ABC{TAB}XYZ{Enter}
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "2")
{
  Sleep, 500
  Send, {Esc}  
  Sleep, 100
  Send, XYZ{TAB}ABC{Enter}
  Return
}

if (CI_KeyVar = "q")
{
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "s")
{
  DllCall("PowrProf\SetSuspendState", "int", 0, "int", 0, "int", 0)
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "b")
{
  GoSub, NetBackup
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "r")
{
  run, Shutdown.exe /r /t 1 ; Reboot PC
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "p")
{
  run, Shutdown.exe /s /t 0 ; Shutdown PC
  Return
}
if (CI_KeyVar = "w")
{
SleepTime+=1
inputbox, Sleeptime, Minutes,,,400,110,,,,,%Sleeptime%
Sleeptimer+=%Sleeptime%
MySleeptimer:=Sleeptimer * 60000 ; 60`000 = 1 minute
if MySleeptimer = 0
{
  Return
}
TrayTip, Count Down,`n`nSleeping in %Sleeptimer% minutes`n`nPress Alt + Esc to cancel,10,1
SetTimer, GoToSleep, %Mysleeptimer%
}
Return
```